# phpDocumentor and @global keyword

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is my use of `@global` correct in the following case?

```
// File: my_special_class.php
<?php
...
class MySpecialClass {

    function display_template() {
        // Following variable will be available from context of 'template.php':
        $instance = array( 'title' => 'Test Page' );

        include('template.php');
    }

}

// File: template.php
<?php
/**
 * Template for ...
 *
 * @copyright Me
 * @version 1
 *
 * @global array $instance Template instance parameters.
 */
?>
<h1><?php echo $instance['title']; ?></h1>
```

Is there a standard way of documenting this?

It is primarily a reminder for those reading the code, but it would be useful if this information was also present under phpDocumentor generated documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your $instance variable is not in the global scope, based on this code... it is local to the MySpecialClass::display_template() function only.

If you want to highlight, from the template.php documentation page, that there is something of significance to the reader with regard to the $instance variable, you could use the @see tag in template.php's file-level docblock (the location that you currently have the @global tag) to point the reader to the MySpecialClass's function that sets $instance:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for ...
 *
 * @copyright Me
 * @version 1
 *
 * @see MySpecialClass::display_template() to see how $instance is populated
 */
?>
<h1><?php echo $instance['title']; ?></h1>
```

Comment: I was worried that might be the case. Do you know how easy it would be to add a new custom attribute `@local` to phpdocumentor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to highlight by using a custom tag like @local, but you certainly can make @local appear in your docs. You can configure *any* kind of custom tag (e.g. @foo, @bar, @treehouse) by listing the tag name in the --customtags runtime option -- http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.command-line.customtags

Comment: thanks for the link I'll experiment with that. I just want to highlight what variables are in scope in the template script, and what their purposes are.